# What is Best Approach for Opening/Closing SqlConnection in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection, sql-server-2008r2-express

I would like to know what could be best approach to open a `SqlConnection` with `Sql Server 2008R2 Express Edition` Database. This Version of Sql has Limitations of RAM Usage and CPU Usage so we must adopt something best to open a `SqlConnection`.

Right Now i am Checking Connection on Start and End of each and every Method. Here is an example of that.

```
   private void CheckValidId(string Id)
    {
        CheckConnectionStatus();

        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from ValidId where id=@id", sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
            sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            While (sqlDataReader.Read())
            {
               string Test = sqlDataReader["Id"].toString();
               MessageBox.Show("Value of Id : " , Test);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message.ToString(), "Exception in CheckValidId");
        }
        finally
        {
            CheckConnectionStatus();
        }
    }
```

Here is `CheckConnectionStatus` Method

```
    private void CheckConnectionStatus()
    {
        if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

What is best approach to perform this operation.

Thanks

Comment: the two answers below are the correct answers for you, the reason you want to use a using statement is because its disposable. It will automatically close the connection when its completed

Comment: @SimonPrice thanks man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern for open and close is correct. However you must note that this doesn't open and close the connection to the SQL Server so doesn't really address your concerns over memory usage and CPU - in fact it wont make any difference.

What Open and Close does is lease and return a connection to the ADO Connection Pool on the client PC. This means that Closing an ADO connection is not guaranteed (and in most cases will not) close and release the connection to the SQL Server. This is becasue establishing and authenticating a connection is relatively expensive and slow, so the ADO connection pool keeps your connections in a pool, still open, just in case you want to re-establish a connection.

What makes the difference to SQL Server is the number of concurrent queries it needs to execute - and the dataset size of the queries, and the total size of the data in the database.

Concurrent queries squeeze CPU, and the datasets returned squeeze the RAM available. Obviously the bigger your database the less can be cached in RAM and so the less likely you are to get a cache hit when querying.

In practice my experience with SQL Express editions is that you wont notice any difference between it and the full edition of SQL Server unless you are doing some very specific things;

1) Writing a BI style tool which allows the user to construct user-defined or user-scoped queries.
2) Writing terrible SQL - "big SQL" may mask your bad query syntax, but Express wont be able to because it has less available RAM to play with.

If you write efficient, constrained SQL, you probably wont actually ever hit any of SQL Express's limitations.

Comment: thanks for replying in details. I have maximum 10 queries that are running continuously. I am feeling performance issue since couple of months. I think there is some deadlock. Coz when i am restarting Server everything is going to be normal. So do you think this is issue with `Express Version Limitation` ?. Should i upgrade it to `Standard Version` or should i recheck my C# for any loophole ?

Comment: You have 10 concurrent queries, or 10 queries that you are running in a loop ? If its 10 queries running in a loop then SQL Express is not your problem. Even if you have 10 concurrent queries running endlessly, then I wouldn't expect SQL Express to have any problem with that either. 

Rebooting the server should make no difference at all. Try all the normal stuff (i.e. Windows Performance Monitor, SQL Server Profiler) to see whats going on in your server.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `using` as it disposes of the connection once done.

```
 using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connection string")){
  //do sql stuff
  conn.Open(); 
  //etc etc
  conn.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Man for your kind suggestion

Comment: Note: `conn.Close();` is optional as when you dispose the connection, it will close the connection automatically

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to make use of the disposable pattern to ensure everything is closed and disposed properly:

```
var query = "select * from ValidId where id=@id";

using (var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(usingConnectionString))
using (var command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Id;
    conn.Open;

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string Test = reader["Id"].ToString();
        }
    }

    command.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

You don't need to check the connection state; it will close when it's being disposed.

One thing to note: it's best practice to explicitly specify your parameter data types.  I've assumed `SqlDbType.Int` in your case, but you can change it to whatever it really is.

Another thing to note: you don't want to do too much inside the reader while loop.  You want to build your collection or whatever and get out of there.  The shorter your connection is open, the better.  That's because you could potentially be holding a read lock on some of the rows in the database that might affect other users and their applications.

Comment: The connection must be opened manually unless you use the Fill() method on the Data Adapter which automatically opens (and closes) it for you. What are you using the adapter for in your example? It appears to be unused?

Comment: @DanDef -- Yeah, I adapted a snippet that uses a data adapter to the data reader for this question; my bad.  I didn't know ExecuteReader doesn't open the connection, good to know.

Comment: @rory.ap is there effect of Using Statement on the performance ? I mean if i will use Using Statement it will make my application faster ?

Comment: @محمدخرمشھزاد -- no it's not about making it faster, it's about resiliency and correctness.  If your application throws an exception while you're reading from the reader, the `using` statement guarantees that all disposables will be disposed before it exists the block.